# Ad networks that will serve via HTTPS?

Tags: web-development, https, advertising

I've built a website with 160K page views per month that serves *every page* over HTTPS. The recent FireSheep news will probably increase the adoption of "HTTPS everywhere" but it's been very hard to find ad networks and affiliates that will serve their content via HTTPS.

I don't want to use these because I don't want my visitors to get "broken security" notification from their browsers (and of course, relevant ads *would* be a leak of private information).

I'm tired of spending a ton of time signing up with ad networks and affiliates only to find out down the road that they don't support HTTPS (e.g. AdSense).

Can anyone suggest any options or provide a pointer to a list of these somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Openx](http://www.openx.org) seems to have a work around: http://www.openx.org/support/faqs/troubleshooting

On another note, why do you server *every* page over HTTPS? Is that absolutely necessary?

Comment: this is related to the whole firesheep thing.. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/breaking-the-webs-cookie-jar.html

Comment: What I was getting at is what is the OP's website? Is it absolutely necessary to display every page using SSL if it's a wordpress blog for example?

Comment: @Jeff, yep, firesheep is going to push a lot of people to begin using https on many more pages than they currently do.

Comment: But of course, this weakness has been out there all along. My site's been all-ssl for a while: it's for legal research, and so there are a lot of important privacy interests to protect. E.g., attorneys working for a client, or a person researching a private matter. https://www.oregonlaws.org/blog/tag/security/

Answer (score 3):

In mid-September 2013, Google AdSense [added HTTPS support](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2013/09/https-compatible-ad-code-for-adsense.html). Consider using it if your site's privacy policy would allow sharing page content with Google.